# Using a list with much text inside a fixed width table

Tags: tables, lists, tabularx

I want to format interviews which are pretty long. I decided to split each interviews into sections with relevant tags. You can see a screenshot of this idea below. How can I accomplish something similar with Latex? It's necessary that the table has the same width as the article's text.

[image: Formatting to be accomplished]

I have already tried something as you can see below, but I get formatting issues.

```
\begin{table}[caption={Colors defined by the template}, 
    label=tab:colors]
  \begin{center}
       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | c | c | c |}
        \hline
       \thead{Section} & \thead{Content} & \thead{Tag} \\
      \hline
    1 &  \makecell{A: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  \\ Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum .
        \\ F: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum  \\ Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum }  & Preprocessing  \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

I appreciate every contribution!

Comment: Use `X` instead of `c` in `tabularx`'s column definition for the centre column that contains all that text. Also drop the `\makecell` in that column, the line breaks will be set automatically.

Comment: Also you shouldn't nest `center` inside a `table` environment. Instead use `\centering`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Using X instead of c as well as dropping \makecell solved the problem for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I'd typeset your table:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Colors defined by the template\label{tab:colors}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{  c  X  l }
    \toprule
    Section & Content & Tag \\
    \midrule
    1 &
    A: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum .
     F: Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum   Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
    & Preprocessing  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want a line break prior to the "F:" you can either use `\newline` inside of the `X` type column or use another table row.

Comment: It works for me! Thank you. For writing F's comment into a new line I just use /newline.